# Target native dom element <input>...</input> with styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am having trouble getting my styled component to make a change to an `<input />` wrapped in a React component. In Dev Tools I can see the style I am trying to override here:

```
.ui.input input {...}
```

I think the wrapping component needs to pass `className` to input i.e

```
<input className = {this.props.className} ..> ... </input>
```

but I cannot get the style to override with or without that. I will provide some snippets below.

```
//styled component
const StyledSearch = styled(Searchbar)`
  &.ui.input input{
    border: 0px !important;
  }
`;


class SearchBar extends Component {
...
render() {
const style = {
  display: this.state.showResults ? 'block' : 'none',
  maxHeight: 500,
  overflowY: 'scroll',
};
return (
  <div className="ui search fluid" ref="container">
    <div
      className={`ui icon fluid input ${this.props.loading ? 'loading' : ''}`}>
      <input type="text"
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        onFocus={this.focus}
        className = {this.props.className}
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
      <i className="search icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div
      className="results"
      style={style}>

      {
        this.props.results.map((result, index) => (
            <a
              className="result"
              key={index}
              onClick={this.select.bind(this, result)}>
              <div className="content">
                {
                  result.get('image') ?
                  (
                    <div className="image">
                      <img src={result.get('image')} style={{ maxWidth: 50 }}/>
                    </div>
                  ) : null
                }
                <div className="title">
                  {result.get('title')}
                </div>
                <div className="description">
                  {result.get('description')}
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          )
        )
      }
    </div>
  </div>
);}}
```

Comment: can we get a little more html

Comment: added @GerardoBLANCO thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `styled-components` creates a **new unique class name** (in other words, a new namespace) for any DOM or React Components for which the `styled` function is called.

That means, when you use `styled(SearchBar)`, `styled-components` wraps `SearchBar` component and attaches a unique class name to its root DOM. Then it passes that unique class name to the descendent DOMs and components (in your cases, nested `div`, `input`, `a`).

For this method to work, your root DOM must have a `className` that can be configured from outside. That's why, `styled-components` expects that, root DOM has the definition `${this.props.className}` as the value of its `className` props. If your component lacks this, `styled-components` will not be able to create a new namespace which it can use to apply styling specific to it.

So, for your technique to work, **you must assign `${this.props.className}` as one of the values of `className` prop defined at the root `div` of `SearchBar`**.

[**Working Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9wj9vvzn9)

If you don't have access to `SearchBar`, you can wrap it with another component. Overhead of this process is that, you have to use an extra DOM level

[**Working Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/xzxmkm6mpw)

Comment: why do you have this.props.className in the <input> tag as well

Comment: Not needed. result of copy-pasting code from your sample. Edited

Comment: why did wrapping it in a div fix it. The div doesn't have `className = {this.props.className}'

Comment: Because `styled-component` can generate unique class for the wrapper component, thus maintaining a new namespace.That's why the `${this.props.classname}` definition is not needed here.

Comment: kind of makes sense. Thanks for your time amazing explanation

Comment: the root dom on Searchbar is not the parent div in the render method right?

Comment: `in the render method`, by this, if you mean the render method of your sample, then **If you use wrapper component, the wrapper becomes the parent div of SearchBar, if you use `${this.props.className}`, then the root DOM of SearchBar remains the parent**

Comment: [For more details](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components)

Comment: someone at my work cleared up the confusion. ```divs``` natively accept className

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161233/discussion-between-tzvetlin-velev-and-saleh).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you need to apply the styles generated with `styled-components` to the wrapper element. This is due to the specificity of the `.ui.input input` external style. Meaning we can't simply target the `input` element with a new style because the `.ui.input input` selector is more specific and takes precedence. Here's a simple CSS example showing how the specificity of the `.ui.input input` selector takes precedence over the `input` styling:

```css
.ui.input input {
  border:2px solid red !important;
}

input {
  border: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui input">
  <input />
</div>
```

This same issue is at play in your case. In the example below I've created a new `Wrapper` component, which has a style of:

```
&.ui.input input {
  border: 0px !important;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

defined on it. This targets the inner `input` element, with more specificity, to override the external styles.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class InputWrapper extends React.Component {

  render() {
     const Wrapper = styled.div`
       &.ui.input input {
         border: 0px !important;
         font-size: 24px;
       }
     `;

    return(
      <Wrapper className="ui input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Input" />
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <InputWrapper />, 
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Here's a [WebpackBin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-L0H8qCZbG5_VSkQYNhO) example.

Comment: I am applying it to Searchbar which is what renders the 'additional code' block. Thanks for the time.

Comment: @TzvetlinVelev Can you please cleanup the code in your example to represent the actual setup?

Answer (score 0):

Currently at version 4 you can do it as simple as

```
const Input = styled.input`
  border:2px solid red !important;
`;
```

it will rendered as native input with SC className